# How do you ORDER a UNION in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, union

I would like to know, how can we ordered the list (DESC) in Union based mysql_query, We are getting output when we fetch this query in PHP/ MYSQL. but we just simply put the order by in this query.

```
 (SELECT info.id 
 FROM info, 1_all 
 WHERE 1_all.id = info.id and 1_all.table_type = 'disp'  AND 1_all.year = '$year' AND  info.category IN (1,2,3) AND info.area IN (2,5,6)  
 GROUP BY resinfo.id ) 
UNION ALL 
 (SELECT info.id 
 FROM info, 2_all 
 WHERE 2_all.id = info.id and 2_all.table_type = 'disp' AND 2_all.year = '$year' AND info.category IN (1,2,3) AND info.area IN (2,5,6) 
 GROUP BY info.id)
```

Answer (score 4):

> To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION
>   result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the
>   ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one. The following example uses both
>   clauses:
>
> ```
> (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
> UNION
> (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
> ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;
> ```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make an subquery like this:

```
SELECT info.id
FROM
(
  (SELECT info.id 
   FROM info, 1_all 
   WHERE 1_all.id = info.id and 1_all.table_type = 'disp'  AND 1_all.year = '$year' AND     info.category IN (1,2,3) AND info.area IN (2,5,6)  
   GROUP BY resinfo.id ) 
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT info.id 
   FROM info, 2_all 
   WHERE 2_all.id = info.id and 2_all.table_type = 'disp' AND 2_all.year = '$year' AND info.category IN (1,2,3) AND info.area IN (2,5,6) 
   GROUP BY info.id)
) as all
order by id desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if MySQL engine accepts it, but other engins such as SQL Server allow you to add an order by clause at the end :

```
SELECT info.id 
 FROM info, 1_all 
 WHERE 1_all.id = info.id and 1_all.table_type = 'disp'  AND 1_all.year = '$year' AND      info.category IN (1,2,3) AND info.area IN (2,5,6)  
 GROUP BY resinfo.id
UNION ALL 
 SELECT info.id 
 FROM info, 2_all 
 WHERE 2_all.id = info.id and 2_all.table_type = 'disp' AND 2_all.year = '$year' AND     info.category IN (1,2,3) AND info.area IN (2,5,6) 
 GROUP BY info.id
ORDER BY info.id DESC;
```

If your database engine doesn't accept it, maybe your best bet is to create a view based on your union query and then have a query on this view with your order by.